# removing characters from mysql query results in python

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to print a tuple in python from a mysql query.  An example query is as follows:

```
query = ("show databases;")

cursor.execute(query)

for row in cursor.fetchall():

       print (row)
```

The output is as follows:

```
('database1',)
('database2',)
('database3',)
```

How can I remove the characters (parenthesis and single quote) from tuple so that my output looks like this:

```
database1
database2
database3
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The result from `fetchall()` is a `list of tuples` and not a list of strings.

```
print row[0]
```

Comment: Then you could iterate through each tuple.

Answer (score 0):

`fetchall()` returns `tuple of tuples`.
e.g. ((field1 of row1, field2 of row1, field3 of row1), (field1 of row2, field2 of row2, field3 of row2))

`data=fetchall()`
you can access first row as `data[0]`
you can access 2nd row as `data[2]`
you can access 1st filed of first row as `data[0][0]`
you can access 2nd filed of first row as `data[0][1]`
you can access 3rd filed of 2nd row as `data[1][2]`

Answer (score -2):

```
query = ("show databases;")

cursor.execute(query)

result = cursor.fetchall()

for row  in result :

    print ("".join(row  ))
```